# Python module loading with Spyder

Tags: python, tensorflow, import, module, spyder

I am new to using Python for machine learning and I am trying to learn ZhuSuan using Spyder.

I have downloaded and installed Zhusuan as descibed here:  https://zhusuan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/.

I have also tried installing the additional dependencies required for the examples by following the instructions here: https://github.com/wmyw96/ZhuSuan.

I then try and run an example script (eg https://github.com/thu-ml/zhusuan/blob/master/examples/bayesian_neural_nets/bayesian_nn.py), importing the modules as with the code:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import division
import os

import tensorflow as tf
from six.moves import range, zip
import numpy as np
import zhusuan as zs

from examples import conf
from examples.utils import dataset
```

However, on execution, I receive the following error:

```
  File "C:/*******/bayesian_nn.py", line **, in <module>
    from examples import conf

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'examples'
```

I would be very grateful if anyone could anyone help identify where I have gone wrong with loading or importing the example modules.

Many thanks in advance.

Ross

Comment: The code you're trying to run is wrong. It should be `from zhusuan.examples import conf` and the next line `from zhusuan.examples.utils import dataset`.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem.  The additional dependencies had not installed correctly for some reason.  Running a full reinstall fixed the problem, and the program now runs successfully with the original code.  Thanks to Carlos for his comment.